# Java streams - should I use reduce or collect?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I use Java 9. I am learning about Stream operations like collect() and reduce() from [this tutorial](https://stackify.com/streams-guide-java-8/) by Baeldung i.e. EUGEN PARASCHIV.

I have to list all the employee names separated by a comma. The tutorial uses collect() to do that. But, I can do it with reduce() and collect(). I have seen some examples which use collect only to put elements into a collection such as List. So, how do I know when to use reduce() or collect() ?

```
private static Employee[] arrayOfEmps = {
        new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos", 100000.0),
        new Employee(2, "Bill Gates", 200000.0),
        new Employee(3, "Mark Zuckerberg", 300000.0)
};


public static void joiningDemo(){
    //List all the employee names separated by a comma.
    String fromReduce = empList.stream().map(Employee::getName).reduce("", (allNames, oneName) ->  allNames + ", " + oneName);
    fromReduce = fromReduce.substring(2);    
    String fromCollect = empList.stream().map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    System.out.println("reduce : " + fromReduce);
    System.out.println("collect : " + fromCollect);
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
reduce : Jeff Bezos, Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg
collect : Jeff Bezos, Bill Gates, Mark Zuckerberg
```

Comment: The [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) of `java.util.stream` seems to make the distinction that `reduce` is for [reduction operations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and `collect` is for [_mutable_ reduction operations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction), where the latter is a specialization of the former.

Comment: Wherever you find a well tested `collect` alternative for a `reduce`, use it. It's just a specialization built over.

Comment: Your `reduce("", (a,b)->a+", "+b)` variant will produce a leading comma, you surely don’t want. You’d have to use `reduce((a,b)->a+", "+b).orElse("")` instead. The reduce variant will be more efficient when you have two or less stream elements. Perhaps, it even wins for three elements. However, the more elements, the more likely `collect` will be more efficient. And the difference for large numbers is what matters…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collectors.joining(", ")` is basically a reduction - all elements melded together into one value - but it adheres to the contract of a collector because it keeps its own state.

Although it would be instructive for you to implement it as a reduction, I would use Collectors.joining() because 99% of the code is written for you.

Comment: You said that 99% of the code is written for you. Could you please elaborate ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can choose either, use `collect()`. Your example is a good one, typical of the simplicity, clarity, and correctness that a carefully developed and well-tested `Collector` brings to common use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want immutable reduction then you should use `reduce()` or use `collect()` for mutable reduction.

For more details, watch the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7VbRz9aj7c